# Spring JPA Repository Return Object

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

I'm new in Spring. I want to create a repository that return Page of object array like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

public interface A extends JpaRepository<Object, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT a, b FROM EntityA a FULL OUTER JOIN EntityB b ON "
            + "a.id = b.id")
    Page<Object[]> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

But I get:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

Thank you

Comment: try to post EntityA  class

Comment: change JpaRepository<Object, Long>  to JpaRepository<EntityA, Long> then have a try